# Global Protect VPN SSL handshake fails

Tags: networking, vpn

My university uses Global Protect, which I've installed on Ubuntu 22.04.  Via the GUI, I try to log in and get through all of the verifications, which include microsoft 2fa. But then, instead of connecting, I get an error:

> SSL handshake failed
>
> Failed to load URL https://vox.[university]/SAML20/SP/ACS.

The vox subdomain is generally accessible to me in a web browser and this did work previously before I recently had to reinstall my system.

Does anyone have any suggestions of what I might try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The version of Global Protect that came from my institution (and which they got from the company they buy services from) has a known bug with 22.04, but there is a different version in public repos that works fine.

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yuezk/globalprotect-openconnect
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install globalprotect-openconnect

Comment: Alternative client does not actually connect (despite showing "connected" status upon successful authentication).

Comment: It works for some people and not for others. It is by far the safer option.

Answer (score 4):

Following workaround solved the issue for me on Ubuntu 22.04.1 and GlobalProtect 6.0.1-6 (not sure, though, if some system vulnerability may be a potential downside here):

**/usr/lib/ssl/openssl.cnf**

```
[system_default_sect]
Options = UnsafeLegacyRenegotiation
```

Comment: How to download GP 6.0,1?

Comment: I don't think, this fix is specific to the particular version of GP it's rather caused by SSLv3 changes in Ubuntu 22.04, so still should work with older version of GP as well. Back to your question: GP is proprietary software, so, I assume, you should purchase the license or get distribution from IT support team (of the company that grants you access to their internal resources or your own employer, who expects you to use them) if you use GP for business purposes.

Comment: I can confirm this works with GlobalProtect 6.0.4-28!

Comment: I added the line "Options = UnsafeLegacyRenegotiation" to the file and it worked. Mine is GlobalProtect 5.3.